# calculate number ticks from outside of the .net framework

Tags: c#, python, .net, timestamp

Does anyone know how to calculate the number of .net time ticks from outside of the .net framework? my situation involves a python script on Linux (my side) needing to send a timestamp as the number of ticks in a message destined for a C# process (the other side, who can't change its code). I can't find any libraries that do this... Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: `Environment.TickCount` is the number of milliseconds since Windows was started. Linux provides `/proc/uptime` that you could use for this. But how on earth would you reconcile these two different system uptimes? Doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: I'm referring to the ticks which represent a C# Datetime object, so ticks corresponds to the number of 100ns 'ticks' since the date 01/01/01 at 00:00:00. This could be reconciled against Unix time which is zero at 1/1/1970, but because of the changes of calendar etc in the 1500's or something(Julian to Gregorian) I'm not sure how it should be handled exactly correctly - so I'm hoping there is a library somewhere that takes care of all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily determine what the Unix/Linux epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00) is in DateTime ticks:

```
DateTime netTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(netTime.Ticks);
// Prints 621355968000000000
```

Since the Unix/Linux timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, you can convert that to 100ns ticks by multiplying it by `10000000`, and then convert it to DateTime ticks by adding `621355968000000000`:

```
long netTicks = 621355968000000000L + 10000000L * linuxTimestamp;
```

Comment: @aho: If you ever need to try out some C#, you can do so for free online at https://dotnetfiddle.net/ - for example, click this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/X9rsgk